# Access Denied 403 when webscraping; What to do?

Tags: python, web-scraping, server, http-headers, http-status-code-403

I was testing a scraping algorithm that I had built. I made a request to https://www2.hm.com/fi_fi/miesten.html but misspecified the user-agent information. It seems that this triggered an immediate ban (not sure) Scraping their site should be fine - their robots.txt says: User-agent: *
Disallow: )

[Example of making a request to HM and the subsequent server response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRsyu.png)

I erased the user agent and proxy information due to privacy concerns. However, they are nothing out of the ordinary.

I receive the following as response:

"b'\nAccess Denied\n\n

\n \nYou don't have permission to access "http://www2.hm.com/fi_fi/miesten.html" on this server.

\nReference #18.2796ef50.1625728417.f9aab80\n\n\n'"

So my question is: **is there anything that I can do to lift this ban? Can i connect someone from their end and ask to lift it? If so, where can this information usually be found.**
Although this question concern this site in particular, this is a much broader question. In the case of a ban, can the user try to connect someone from the server? I thought about contacting customer support, but I heavily suspect they they cannot help with this issue, and won't even understand what it is about.

I have googled this issue, but not found anything of help. They usually advise to clear cache, memory etc. This is not the problem here. I can access the site via Chrome or other browsers, but when using requests via python, this problem appears.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to use a Javascript scraping bot, you can try with this tool: https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/

And to get contact informations about the owner of a website you can use the unix whois command:

`whois hm.com`

Comment: This is not the case, because the scraper worked fine for a few weeks with this implementation.

Comment: Try to clear cookies and change your IP address

Comment: Check the technical / contact emails for the domain (`whois hm.com`) and please don't be rude with people trying to help you! Be polite in your demand and maybe they will respond...

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I did not mean to be rude (now reading back, my reply seems hostile)